# Computing expected value of dependent random variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

> A graph $G=(V, E)$ has $2n$ vertices of which $n$ are coloured in blue and $n$ are coloured in red. The probability that there is an edge between any two vertices is $1/2$. Let $X$ denote the expected number of edges whose endpoints have the same colour. Compute the expected value of $X$.

Let $Y$ denote the number of edges whose endpoints have the colour blue.
We define
\begin{align*}
 Y_{\{u, v\} }:=\begin{cases}
  1,\ \text{there exists an edge and }u, v\text{ are blue}\\[5pt]
  0, \ \text{else}
 \end{cases}
.\end{align*}
We then have
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E}[Y]=\sum_{\{u, v\} \subseteq V}^{} \mathbb{E}\left[ Y_{\{u, v\} } \right]
 = \binom{|V|}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{8}
.\end{align*}
We get the same result for the expected number of edges whose endpoints are
red, let $Z$ be the respective random variable.
Because $X=Y+Z$ we finally obtain
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y+Z]= \mathbb{E}[Y]+\mathbb{E}[Z]=
 \frac{1}{4}\cdot \binom{|V|}{2} 
.\end{align*}

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not correct.

I will not immediately point out the flaw in your reasoning, in case you prefer to find the flaw by yourself. One way to see that your answer is wrong is by doing the following sanity check: is this the right answer for small values of $n$?

For $n = 1$, there are two vertices with different colours, with an edge between them with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. However, there are no edges between vertices of the same colour, so the answer should be $0$. But your formula gives $\frac{1}{4} \cdot \binom{2}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$.

Maybe it helps if you work out the answer for $n = 2$, and then see how you can generalize this solution. If you figure it out, feel free to answer the question yourself. Otherwise, let us know if you need more help!

---

*Added later (as requested).* The flaw in your reasoning is this. In your solution, the equality $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\sum_{\{u, v\} \subseteq V}^{} \mathbb{E}\left[ Y_{\{u, v\} } \right]$ is valid. However, we don't have $\mathbb{E}\left[ Y_{\{u,v\}} \right] = \frac{1}{8}$, but rather
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ Y_{\{u,v\}} \right] = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2},&\text{if $u$ and $v$ are blue};\\[1ex] 0,&\text{otherwise}. \end{cases} $$
After all, the expected value ranges over all edge realizations, but the colours are fixed. So if either $u$ or $v$ is not blue, then we have $Y_{\{u,v\}} = 0$ for all possible edge realizations.

Comment: Could you specify  where my mistake lies? I can't really find it.

Comment: @Max fair enough; your mistake was rather subtle. I edited my answer to pinpoint what exactly went wrong.

Comment: I still don't really get it yet. $Y_{\{u, v\}}$ is my indicator variable and for a specific  edge to have both endpoints coloured in blue the probability is $1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2$ since there is a $1/2$ chance for the edge being present and a $1/2$ chance for each of the vertices to be part of the blue coloured set of vertices

Comment: @Max the expectation ranges over the probability experiment. As far as I can tell from your question, the colours of the vertices are fixed and not part of the experiment. (In other words, only the edges are random variables.) Therefore the probability that vertex $u$ (or $v$) is blue is either $0$ (if it is red) or $1$ (if it is blue), and never $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: (Of course, you could decide to pick a vertex at random, but that's a different probability experiment, resulting in a different expected value. Here you are summing over all pairs of vertices. So $u$ and $v$ are not random but fixed, and so are their colours.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally got it!

Comment: I've added a bit two my  question, it would be great if you could take a look at it!

Comment: @Max in the interest of fairness to myself and the other user who answered your question, I think it would be better if you revert your edits and start a new question. You can then add links between the two questions to make it easier for others to find the related question.

Comment: Can we just say the number of edges with both endpoints being blue is $\text{Binomial}\Big({n \choose 2},\frac{1}{2}\Big)$ which has expected value ${n \choose 2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$. Since the distribution of the number of edges with red endpoints is the same as those with blue endpoints we have $E(X)={n \choose 2}$

Comment: @MatthewPilling yes, that is a more elegant argument. My answer focused on pointing out the flaw in OP's solution, not finding the most elegant answer (as that was not the question).

Comment: I understand. I'm just asking to satisfy my own curiosity. I've never taken graph theory and I was wondering if my approach on this problem was legit. Thank you.

Comment: @MatthewPilling No problem! I guess you could even add this as a separate answer, even if it doesn't literally answer OP's question ("Is my solution correct?"). There is already another answer like that (but not as elegant), and I doubt that others will be downvoting your contribution. Anyway, it's up to you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Linearity of expectation is a good tool for these types of problems.

Label the vertices as $P_1,P_2,\ldots ,P_{2n}$ where $P_1,P_2,\ldots ,P_n$ are red and $P_{n+1},P_{n+2},\ldots P_{2n}$ are blue.

Define a random variable $x_i$ which returns the number of same-color edges with endpoint of $P_i$.

We want to find the value of
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{2n} x_i\right)$$
By linearity of expectation, this is
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{2n} \mathbb{E}(x_i)$$
By symmetry, we have $\mathbb{E}(x_i)=\mathbb{E}(x_j)$, hence this is equivalent to
$$n\mathbb{E}(x_1)$$
To calculate $\mathbb{E}(x_1)$ we again use linearity of expectation.

Define a random variable $y_i$ for $2\leq i\leq 2n$ which takes a value of $1$ if there is an edge connecting $x_1$ to $x_i$ for $2\leq i\leq n$ and is $0$ otherwise.

We have
$$\mathbb{E}(x_i)$$
$$=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=2}^{2n} y_i\right)$$
$$=\mathbb{E}\left(0+\sum_{i=2}^{n}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{i=2}^n \mathbb{E}(y_i)$$
By symmetry, we have $\mathbb{E}(y_i)=\mathbb{E}(y_j)$ for $2\leq i,j\leq n$. Hence, our expression is equivalent to
$$=(n-1)\mathbb{E}(y_2)$$
Since $\mathbb{E}(y_2)=\frac{1}{2}(0)+\frac{1}{2}(1)=\frac{1}{2}$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}(x_1)=\frac{n-1}{2}$$

Combining these two, we have that the expected value of $X$ is
$$n\mathbb{E}(x_1)$$
$$\boxed{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$